# Expression templates toy example: user-defined cast not applied for complex types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am trying to build a toy example for expression trees using modern C++17 based on [this blogpost](https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2019/10/20/we-dont-need-no-stinking-expression-templates/). The code works fine for primitive types like `int` or `double`. However, when I try it with something like an  `Eigen::Vector3d` the build fails because the user-defined cast `operator result_t() const` is not applied correctly (I assume).

Can someone give me a hint what exactly is the reason for the failure?

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template <class T, class U, class Callable>
struct BinaryExpression {

    const T* left {nullptr};
    const U* right {nullptr};
    Callable callable;

    BinaryExpression(const T& t, const U& u, const Callable c)
        : left(&t), right(&u), callable(c) {}

    auto operator()() const
    {
        return callable(*left, *right);
    }

    using result_t = decltype(std::declval<Callable>()(std::declval<const T&>(), std::declval<const U&>()));
    operator result_t() const
    {
        return this->operator()();
    }
};

struct Plus {
    template <class T, class U>
    auto operator()(const T& left, const U& right) const
    {
        return left + right;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Eigen::Vector3d v1 (1, 2, 3);
    Eigen::Vector3d v2 (1, 2, 3);

    int num1 = 1;
    double num2 = 2.4;

    BinaryExpression expr(num1, num2, Plus{});
    BinaryExpression expr2(num2, expr, Plus{}); // this works fine

    BinaryExpression expr3(v1, v2, Plus{});
    BinaryExpression expr4(expr3, v1, Plus{}); // why does this give an error?
}
```

Compiler error message

```
../main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘auto Plus::operator()(const T&, const U&) const [with T = BinaryExpression<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Plus>; U = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>]’:
.../main.cpp:36:55:   required from ‘struct BinaryExpression<BinaryExpression<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Plus>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Plus>’
.../main.cpp:63:45:   required from here
.../main.cpp:47:21: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const BinaryExpression<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Plus>’ and ‘const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>’)
         return left + right;
                ~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

I understand that `operator+` is not defined for adding a `BinaryExpression` with a `Matrix` type. However, I expect the code to apply the user-defined cast of `BinaryExpression` which evaluates it to a `Matrix` and therefore calls the `operator+` for adding two `Matrix` types.

Comment: It's somewhere in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), potentially in exactly how `Matrix + Matrix` is defined. Did the error message continue with candidates that were rejected?

Comment: Also note that Eigen [already does lazy evaluation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html) via expression templates

Comment: What `operator+` do you expect to be invoked? Can you show the signature?

Comment: I expect that the inner `BinaryExpression` is casted (which means called the `operator()`) and therefore becomes a `Matrix` type. Then the `operator+` should be defined for `Matrix` + `Matrix`. I know that Eigen does lazy evaluation, this is because I want to use expression templates in another context.

Comment: "the operator+ should be defined for Matrix + Matrix". There probably isn't one.

Comment: I don't think that's true, I can do `auto v3 = v1 + v2` without any issues in the above example.

Comment: "I can do auto v3 = v1 + v2" This unfortunately doesn't mean that an operator you want to use exists. There is probably an operator *template* in there somewhere, but these work rather differently from normal functions.

Answer (score 0):

line 47 is that they dont know the type of variable "left" and "right".
If you add an int with a string, it will produces error.

Comment: The types of left and right are shown just after in the error message..

Comment: I had an error in my main, but the question is still valid. I edited the question.